# "Loss/regularization_loss'&"classification_loss" is high during the training of a object detection model with "ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17_tpu-8"

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, loss

I am trying to train a model for object-detection with "ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17_tpu-8" with my own datas in my local pc. The problem is "Loss/regularization_loss" and "Loss/classification_loss" is high during the training. This is how it is,

```
I0313 12:02:59.305537  3000 model_lib_v2.py:705] Step 1300 per-step time 2.458s
INFO:tensorflow:{'Loss/classification_loss': 66547.22,
 'Loss/localization_loss': 3.502803,
 'Loss/regularization_loss': 2212851.2,
 'Loss/total_loss': 2279402.0,
 'learning_rate': 0.0405284}
I0313 12:02:59.344294  3000 model_lib_v2.py:708] {'Loss/classification_loss': 66547.22,
 'Loss/localization_loss': 3.502803,
 'Loss/regularization_loss': 2212851.2,
 'Loss/total_loss': 2279402.0,
 'learning_rate': 0.0405284}
```

My configuration is,

```
# SSD with Mobilenet v2
# Trained on COCO17, initialized from Imagenet classification checkpoint
# Train on TPU-8
#
# Achieves 22.2 mAP on COCO17 Val

model {
  ssd {
    inplace_batchnorm_update: true
    freeze_batchnorm: false
    num_classes: 3
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
        use_matmul_gather: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    encode_background_as_zeros: true
    anchor_generator {
      ssd_anchor_generator {
        num_layers: 6
        min_scale: 0.2
        max_scale: 0.95
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        aspect_ratios: 3.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.3333
      }
    }
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 300
        width: 300
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      convolutional_box_predictor {
        min_depth: 0
        max_depth: 0
        num_layers_before_predictor: 0
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 0.8
        kernel_size: 1
        box_code_size: 4
        apply_sigmoid_to_scores: false
        class_prediction_bias_init: -4.6
        conv_hyperparams {
          activation: RELU_6,
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.00004
            }
          }
          initializer {
            random_normal_initializer {
              stddev: 0.01
              mean: 0.0
            }
          }
          batch_norm {
            train: true,
            scale: true,
            center: true,
            decay: 0.97,
            epsilon: 0.001,
          }
        }
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'ssd_mobilenet_v2_keras'
      min_depth: 16
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      conv_hyperparams {
        activation: RELU_6,
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 0.00004
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            stddev: 0.03
            mean: 0.0
          }
        }
        batch_norm {
          train: true,
          scale: true,
          center: true,
          decay: 0.97,
          epsilon: 0.001,
        }
      }
      override_base_feature_extractor_hyperparams: true
    }
    loss {
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid_focal {
          alpha: 0.75,
          gamma: 2.0
        }
      }
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
          delta: 1.0
        }
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    normalize_loc_loss_by_codesize: true
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 1e-8
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
  }
}

train_config: {
  fine_tune_checkpoint_version: V2
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17_tpu-8/checkpoint/ckpt-0"
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"
  batch_size: 24
  sync_replicas: true
  startup_delay_steps: 0
  replicas_to_aggregate: 8
  num_steps: 50000
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    ssd_random_crop {
    }
  }
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: .08
          total_steps: 50000
          warmup_learning_rate: 0.02666
          warmup_steps: 5000
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  max_number_of_boxes: 100
  unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false
}

train_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "labelmap.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "train.record"
  }
}

eval_config: {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
}

eval_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "labelmap.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_epochs: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "test.record"
  }
}
```

How can I reduce the loss specially the regularization loss. I have tried reducing the learning rate to .08 and increasing the batch size to 24.